# How do I hide the total row in my pivot table?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently working on a project where I import rows from another excel file into my pivot table. The pivot table include a total row (that can be removed thanks to a checkbox), but I'd like to do it automatically with vba. Do you know a code that could work and remove this row, then add it again as last raw after the importation?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you not try recording a macro before asking this? I just did this and got the following:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    .ColumnGrand = False
    .RowGrand = False
End With
```

Just tailor this to your sheet and pivot table.

Comment: Ok thanks CLR, seems like a rookie question but how do you record a macro? I usually don't use vba

Comment: On the Developer Tab of Excel's ribbon, there should be a 'Record Macro' 'button'. Once activated, it will change to 'Stop Recording' which, as it suggests, will cease the recording of your actions. It's worth mentioning that not *all* actions are captured, but most.